# Open a server hosted file (from a desktop) using IP not working, but using name works

Tags: networking, microsoft-office, file-permissions

I've a strange issue when trying to open a Word .doc, docx or an excel file .xlsx (haven't tried other files types):

- If I double click a file hosted on Windows 2019 by traversing to it with a desktop PC (Windows 11 Pro) using the name e.g. \servername\folder\ it opens the file in Word/Excel without an issue.
- Lately (wasn't an issue a month or so ago and I haven't changed
  anything on the server and the server admin is stumped) if I double
  click the same file but traverse to it using the IP e.g.
  \192.168.10.23\folder\ then the file opens in Word but opens in
  protected view and says that it has Disaster Recovered the file, if I
  then click on the recovered file that it displays within a panel in
  Word, then the file does not open.

I've restarted the server and my pc but the issue is still there.

I can open word files on my local pc desktop without issue, I can also copy across one of the files it thinks that it needs to recover and that also opens without issue.

I'm a bit stumped here.

P.S. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ sent me here to ask this!

Comment: Is the server and/or the client part of an Active Directory domain? Is either of the UNC locations in your "Trusted locations" list in Office (Word) settings?

Comment: Both client/server are part of the same AD domain. I'm trying to check in Word but now when I try to open the doc on the desktop that it was working with, it opens it, but it also tries to recover the networked doc that I'm having the issue with, and word is now hanging for over 5 mins... I'm going to 'repair' and try again.

Comment: If they're in a domain, you shouldn't really be _using_ IP addresses at all, as such paths will not work with Kerberos... (and the previous "default" alternative – NTLM – is increasingly being disabled by sysadmins.) I'm not sure where the problem is, but I rather suspect it has to do with that – especially with NTLM's unfortunate property that it would outright leak your credentials when opening a malicious Office doc that had an image embedded from a UNC \\path (NTLM has no way to verify the server it's talking to), so it's plausible that Office would have received some hardening against it.

Comment: Okidoke, it seems as though you may be right about the hardening. I suspect when Microsoft introduced changes to their Office 365 offering; changing things to 'business', e.g. their rationale being that people work in a more hybrid fashion and use their same machine for work and play, I came up against this with OneDrive, you now have a private and a business logon. Cheers... UNC it is then!

Comment: As a side note (same office version same doc) this isn't an issue on Windows 10 (although using an IP it does open in protected mode), only Windows 11 it attempts to open in protected mode but then tries to recover the doc, thinks it has but then will not open what it thinks it has recovered.